# pass unique json data into handlebar templates using gulp-compile-handlebars

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js

In my **index.handlebars** file I'm doing this:

```
{{> article id = 'section-1'}}
{{> article id = 'section-2'}}
```

As you can see I'm passing a unique Id into each article template instance, so they can be targeted individually. I'm doing this because I want **gulp-compile-handlebars** to populate each article template instance with unique content that I specify in my **build.json** file. However I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to correctly do this in my gulp task. Code below...

In my **gulpfile.js** I'm doing this:

```
gulp.task('compileHandlebars', function () {
    var buildSettings = require('./build.json');
    var templateData = buildSettings,
    options = {
        batch : ['./src/assets/templates/'],
    }

    gulp.src('src/index.handlebars')
        .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

In my **build.json** I'm doing this:

```
{
    "section-1":[{
        "title": "",
        "paragraph": "",
        "backgroundImageUrl": "",
        "figCaption": ""
    }],
    "section-2":[{
        "title": ",
        "paragraph": "",
        "backgroundImageUrl": "",
        "figCaption": ""
    }]
}
```

and finally in my **article.handlebars** template I'm doing this:

```
<section class="row article-module-4" id="{{id}}">
    <div class="col-md-5"> 
        {{#if title}}
            <header>
                <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            </header>
        {{/if}}
        <p>{{paragraph}}</p>
        </div>
    <figure class="col-md-7">
        <div class="figure-img" style="background-image: url('{{backgroundImageUrl}}');"></div>
        <figcaption>{{figCaption}}</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: Try to read and use the examples on theses pages http://tompennington.co.uk/generating-multiple-static-html-pages-with-gulp-and-handlebars/ https://metabroadcast.com/blog/precompilation-of-templates-with-handlebars http://www.federicosilva.net/2016/09/inmadusacom-part-3-use-gulp-to.html

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit scatterbrained last night when I asked this... This morning I found the solution for what I want to do...

**index.handlebars**

```
{{#each this}}
    {{> article}}
{{/each}}
```

**article template**

```
{{#article}}
    <section class="row article-module" id="{{id}}">
        <div class="col-md-5"> 
            {{#if title}}
                <header>
                    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
                </header>
            {{/if}}
            <p>{{paragraph}}</p>
            </div>
        <figure class="col-md-7">
            <div class="figure-img" style="background-image: url('{{backgroundImageUrl}}');"></div>
            <figcaption>{{figCaption}}</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
{{/article}}
```

**build.json**

```
[
    {
        "article": [
            {
                "id": "section-1",
                "title": "Section 1",
                "paragraph": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra aliquet justo posuere rhoncus. Donec tempus eros sed rhoncus fermentum. Mauris nec congue quam. Morbi ullamcorper augue sed quam lacinia interdum. Duis porttitor iaculis posuere. Donec quis facilisis metus, id posuere ex. Vestibulum tincidunt enim a vehicula ultrices. Vestibulum rhoncus tincidunt augue ut ultrices. Aliquam quis sapien et erat varius fringilla. Nullam finibus pellentesque tortor eget tempus. Donec ultricies quam quis mi tincidunt imperdiet. Pellentesque porta euismod ipsum, ut finibus elit malesuada nec. Vivamus vehicula viverra arcu eu feugiat. Integer dapibus est ac gravida blandit. Morbi malesuada, sem non tincidunt iaculis, enim nisi congue tellus, ac pellentesque dolor neque in lacus. Donec non sem vitae felis accumsan dapibus tristique ut justo.",
                "backgroundImageUrl": "assets/images/ocean2.jpg",
                "figCaption": "news.com.au"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "article": [
            {
                "id": "section-2",
                "title": "Section 2",
                "paragraph": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra aliquet justo posuere rhoncus. Donec tempus eros sed rhoncus fermentum. Mauris nec congue quam. Morbi ullamcorper augue sed quam lacinia interdum. Duis porttitor iaculis posuere. Donec quis facilisis metus, id posuere ex. Vestibulum tincidunt enim a vehicula ultrices. Vestibulum rhoncus tincidunt augue ut ultrices. Aliquam quis sapien et erat varius fringilla. Nullam finibus pellentesque tortor eget tempus. Donec ultricies quam quis mi tincidunt imperdiet. Pellentesque porta euismod ipsum, ut finibus elit malesuada nec. Vivamus vehicula viverra arcu eu feugiat. Integer dapibus est ac gravida blandit. Morbi malesuada, sem non tincidunt iaculis, enim nisi congue tellus, ac pellentesque dolor neque in lacus. Donec non sem vitae felis accumsan dapibus tristique ut justo.",
                "backgroundImageUrl": "assets/images/ocean3.jpg",
                "figCaption": "news.com.au"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```